# Не получается спарсить src картинки

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Не могу спарсить картинку со сканом манги с сайта (а именно - img 
id="mangaPicture"/), возвращает img без src
[ссылка на сайт](http://readmanga.me/tomo_chan_is_a_girl_/vol1/1)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from random import choice, uniform

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_list_presentation(html):
    j = 0

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='simple-tile'):
        href = 'http://readmanga.me' + i.a.get("href")
        print("{0}: {1} : {2}".format(i.a.div.text, href, j))
        j = j + 1 

def get_manga(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    url_array = []

    for option in soup.find_all('option'):
        print (('value: {}, text: {}').format(option['value'], option.text))
        url_array.append(option['value'][:-5])

    for j in range(0, len(url_array)):
        print(url_array[j])


def get_picks(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        #print("{0} : {1}".format("src картинки" , img['src']) )
        print(img)

def get_all(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    for i in soup:
        print(i)

def main():
    url = 'http://readmanga.me/'

    url_manga = 'tomo_chan_is_a_girl_/vol1/1'


    #get_list_presentation(get_html(url + 'list/presentation/'))
    #get_manga(get_html(url + url_manga))
    get_picks(get_html(url + url_manga))
    #get_all(get_html(url + url_manga))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Out

```
  <img alt="Читать мангу Online" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" height="45" 
   id="logo" src="http://res.readmanga.me/static/logo- 
   40326e8b76b0db610fa47f0801711aea.png" title="ReadManga.me -- читай 
   мангу с удовольствием" width="250"/>
  <img alt="Читать мангу Online" class="hidden-lg hidden-md" height="40" 
   id="logo" src="http://res.readmanga.me/static/logo_m- 
   1b2831fef94e15ded4ca97581ad07213.png" title="ReadManga.me -- читай 
   мангу с удовольствием" width="80"/>

  <img id="mangaPicture"/>

  <img alt="" src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/21277900" 
   style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;"/>
```

Comment: То, что элемент виден в веб-инспекторе, совсем не обязательно значит, что этот элемент есть в исходном коде веб-страницы. В исходном коде веб-страницы есть только `<img id="mangaPicture"/>` без каких-либо ссылок.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код и ссылку на сайт текстом. В ином случае вопрос будет закрыт и Вам навряд ли помогут. Насчёт самого вопроса, мне кажется, что там данные динамически подгружаются с помощью `Js`. Можно использовать `Selenium` или попытаться провести реверс инжиниринг кода, чтобы достать ссылку на данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На том сайте картинки передаются не в виде html-тегов, а в javascript. Ищите строку вида `rm_h.init( [[`, например:

```
rm_h.init( [['','http://t9.mangas.rocks/',"auto/14/37/84/img000001.png_res.jpg",640,958]], 0, false);
```

Другими словами, нужно скачать страницу и вытащить из нее эту строку, приведя ее к списку url.

Один из вариантов это поиск и вытаскивание строки через регулярные выражения и парсинг ее методом [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). Парсинг возможен потому что тот массив, что передается в `init` синтаксически совпадает с питоничьим.

Пример:

```
import ast
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests


def get_url_images_from_chapter(url: str) -> list:
    rs = requests.get(url)

    re_expr = r'init\(.*(\[\[.+\]\]).*\)'

    match = re.search(re_expr, rs.text)
    if not match:
        raise Exception('Не получилось из страницы вытащить список картинок главы. '
                        'Используемое регулярное выражение: ', re_expr)

    json_text = match.group(1)
    json_data = ast.literal_eval(json_text)

    return [urljoin(data_url[1], data_url[0] + data_url[2]) for data_url in json_data]


url = 'http://readmanga.me/tomo_chan_is_a_girl_/vol1/1'
imgs = get_url_images_from_chapter(url)
print(imgs)
# ['http://t9.mangas.rocks/auto/14/37/84/img000001.png_res.jpg']

url = 'http://readmanga.me/van_pis/vol1/1?mtr='
imgs = get_url_images_from_chapter(url)
print(imgs)
# ['http://t9.mangas.rocks/auto/00/op/v1ch1/OnePiece_Log01_Chapter001_01.jpg', ...
```

---

**PS.**

А так, я уже делал эту задачку давно, если любопытно, то:

- https://github.com/gil9red/client_readmanga.me
- [Два](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/0685b250ec33a6f4b9296b09e798d78296fdca01/download_volume_readmanga.py)
- [Три](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7063c3255611f48a8149d6110b669b2a21b926d9/flask__webservers/show_and_download_from_readmanga/main.py#L22)