# Как вытянуть словарь из скрипта или преобразовать его в нормальный вид?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Сделал парсер страницы, то что мне нужно лежало в тэге , я вытянул, содержание этого тэга такое
как вытянуть этот словарь? я использовал библиотеки BS и Requests

```
<script>
 window.settings ={"feedPrefix":"dnevnik","rootUrl":"https://kundelik.kz","apiUrl":"https://kundelik.kz/api","environmentPrefix":"kz"};
 </script>
```

Ну или преобразовать это во что-то нормальное, потому что сайт это в дальнейшем преобразует в красивую таблицу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование регулярного выражения для вытаскивания словаря и `ast` для конвертации его в питоничий:

```
import ast
import re

text = """
<script>
 window.settings ={"feedPrefix":"dnevnik","rootUrl":"https://kundelik.kz","apiUrl":"https://kundelik.kz/api","environmentPrefix":"kz"};
 </script>
"""

match = re.search(r'window\.settings\s*=\s*({.+?});', text)
if not match:
    print('Not found window.settings!')
    quit()

settings = ast.literal_eval(match.group(1))
print(settings)
# {'feedPrefix': 'dnevnik', 'rootUrl': 'https://kundelik.kz', 'apiUrl': 'https://kundelik.kz/api', 'environmentPrefix': 'kz'}

print(settings['rootUrl'])
# https://kundelik.kz
```

---

Описание регулярки:

- `\.` -- экранирование точки, чтобы точка была точкой, а не спец-символом
- `\s*` -- означает что возможны пробельные символы (от 0 до ...)
- `({.+?});` -- круглые скобки означают группу символов, что нужно захватить, а `group(1)` как раз вернет группу внутри скобок.
- `{.+?}` -- это ленивый поиск текста с фигурными скобоками и всего что внутри

Можно еще тот словарь распарсить как `json`, но, я думаю, `ast` надежнее, т.к. стоит кавычки сделать одинарными (например `'feedPrefix'`) как парсер `json` не сможет распарсить, т.к. ему подходят только двойные кавычки:

```
import json
...
settings = json.loads(match.group(1))
...
```

---

**PS.**

Вот [тут ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1040133/201445) на задачу, похожую на вашу. Возможно, это будет полезно

Comment: _питоничий_, хд)))))

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, *питонский* звучит намного страннее :)

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: Но появилась другая проблема, вытянуть из кода мне нужно такого же типа элемент, но регулярное выражение которое вы написали для него не работает, он в разы больше и состоит из множества словарей

Comment: увы тот огромный элемент я написать сюда не могу, да и боюсь вы разбираться не станете в этом

Comment: @МаксимСинельников, а скиньте ссылку, чтобы посмотрел и название переменной с словарем, чтобы поиском найти